# Having an int I and number if iterations and a function DrawPoint(x,y) how to draw a circle?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, geometry, point

So we have a function  DrawPoint(x,y) that draws a point, we have to draw some number of points that would look like a circle. How to create such `for(i=0; i<numberOfIterations; i++)` to draw a circle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// (cx, cy) is the center of the circle
// r is the circle radius
// the smaller the granularity, the better the circle will look
// to draw only numberOfIterations points, granularity 
// should be 2*pi / numberOfIterations

for(i=0; i<2*pi; i+=granularity)    
    DrawPoint(cx + r*sin(i), cy + r*cos(i));
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the better algorithms for getting a decent circle is the Bresenham's circle algorithm, also called the [Midpoint circle algorith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm).

The problem with the straight forward, basic circle routines is that they tend to have alias effects and not look right as a result, this algorithm gives a better approximation, though does not strictly fit your `for(;;)` loop requirement, though it is still an iterative loop.